# Cannot execute maven test from command line using tags?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

When I run following commands:

> mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @UserAuthentication"

then I get following error:

```
Unknown lifecycle phase 
".options=src/test/java/Feature --tags @@UserAuthentication". 
You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format 
<plugin-prefix>:<goal> or 
<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>
```

My  POM file is as below:

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>             4.0.0
>             com.test.org
>             Test
>             0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>
> ```
>       <properties>
>           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>           <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
>           <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
>         </properties>
>
>       <build>
>           <pluginManagement>
>             <plugins>
>               <plugin>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
>               </plugin>
>               <plugin>
>                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>                   <version>3.8.0</version>
>               </plugin>
>             </plugins>
>           </pluginManagement>
>        </build>
>
>       <dependencies>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
>               <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
>               <version>3.7.1</version>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>junit</groupId>
>               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>               <version>4.12</version>
>               <scope>test</scope>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>               <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
>               <version>1.2.5</version>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>               <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
>               <version>1.0.5</version>
>               <scope>provided</scope>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>               <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
>               <version>1.2.5</version>
>               <scope>test</scope>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
>               <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
>               <version>3.0.2</version>
>           </dependency>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
>               <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
>               <version>3.1.2</version>
>           </dependency>       
>       </dependencies>  </project>
> ```

My runner class is as follows:

```
  @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features ="src/test/java/Feature",
            glue= "stepDefinitions",
            tags= {"@Pagination,@UserAuthentication"},
            plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}, 
            monochrome = true)

    public class RunnerTest {
        @AfterClass
        public static void writeExtentReport() {
            Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
        }
    }
```

I don't know what I am missing as the goal in order to run the test from command line using tags.

Comment: Did you get the solution?